# Determing power settings

Tags: algebra-precalculus, problem-solving

A company has three machines which output at different wattages(35, 45 and 60).
The 35-watt machine runs best at a power level of 45%.
The 60-watt machine runs best at a power level of 60%.

What is the best power level for the 45-watt machine?

Speed, if applicable, is constant at 100%.

Comment: What is your trying?

Comment: Trying to determine power settings for a project I'm working on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a graph.  Can you solve it from there?

[image]

Comment: So, almost 51%. Yes I have it. Thank you.